# Power BI Dax Calculate subtraction of selected rows

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I have a question regarding selecting specific dates on table.

I have the following table:

| Date | Total orders |
| --- | --- |
| 2021_02_01 | 1000 |
| 2021_01_01 | 900 |
| 2020_12_01 | 800 |
| 2020_11_01 | 700 |
| 2020_10_01 | 600 |
| 2020_09_01 | 500 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020_04_01 | 90 |
| 2020_03_01 | 80 |
| 2020_02_01 | 70 |
| 2020_01_01 | 50 |
| ... | ... |
| 2019_01_01 | 40 |

I have parameter so the user can select a date of interest.

I am trying to create a DAX measure that takes calculates the difference in total orders over the years starting on the chosen date.

For example, if 2021_01_01 is selected, the measure will return:

| year | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 950 (1000(2021_01_01)-50 (2020_01_01)) |
| 2020 | 10 (50 (2020_01_01) - 40 (2019_01_01)) |

and so on for all the data existing in the table

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like something that could better be calculated in the source of the data, for example in SQL using a join.